# 12.1.1 "Part" functionality having issues with Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations

I made some large datasets of SEM micrograph images and metadata in 12.0 and they have been working no problem for several weeks.   but now when I run the notebook in 12.1.1, it seems that it fails to define the Part of the dataset I need.  I just reinstalled 12.0 and the problem is still happening now, so maybe I'm just an idiot.

[image: Dataset]

[image: Output]

Comment: "Raw SEM" appears to not be defined in the original `Association` that makes up the `Dataset`.

Comment: youre right,  that fixed it.  I am an idiot